# From Audit Log in Google Cloud

Tags: google-bigquery

From Audit Log in Google Cloud , how to trace only procedure that has been called and need to know the below parameters. totalProcessedBytes & Slot time etc

XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX